# Name of the class of maps between posets such that $f(x)\le f(y)\implies x\le y$

Tags: terminology, order-theory

Is there a name for such functions $f:\mathfrak{A}\rightarrow\mathfrak{B}$ from a poset $\mathfrak{A}$ to a poset $\mathfrak{B}$ that $$f(x)\le f(y)\implies x\le y$$ (for every $x,y\in\mathfrak{A}$)?

Comment: Increasing functions, I guess.

Comment: Increasing functions (but not necessarily strictly increasing).

Comment: @fleablood But the implication goes the other way...

Comment: Oh, if the implication holds also in the reverse direction, it is an __order embedding__. This is probably what I need

Comment: These are called order-reflecting maps. If both statements imply each other it's called an order embedding.